# Installation failed, trying to install ANY plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization, plugin-contact-form-7

I get the following error for every plugin that I try to install. Can anyone tell me what is causing this?

[image]

Comment: Likely it couldn't store the downloaded file to disk either in-part, or at all. So you either have a disk space issue, or a disk permissions issue that's preventing it from saving the file... could this be the case here?

Comment: Thanks for your help  Paul G, but that i dond´t think that was the issue. I use one of the free hosting and in genereal is there a lot of space and disk issues. But it works again! :)